# Html Select Element - how to overlap option element top-left with select element top-left

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to create an Html List box in html such that there is no space/gap between the option element's top-left coordinate and the select element's top-left.By default there is about 3px gap between them (As shown by Accessibility explorer)

[image]

With respect to the above image, I want to get rid of of the white space between the edges of the option *apple* and the border of the select.
Currently the option *apple* is at offset 3px,3px w.r.t the select element , I want to make the offset as 0px,0px . 
So that if select's screen position is  10,10 , the option's screen position would also be 10,10.

I have seen such thing possible  but can't get the source to see how is it done.(but it was done using asp.net)

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:
Following is how it looks after setting martin to 0px in the Acc Explorer: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Give it a negative margin:
http://jsfiddle.net/zTatx/14/

Comment: Thanks , however even though the margin has been set to -3px . I still get the offset of 1px  when I used accessiblity explorer to get the screen rectangle of the select and the option. Moreover if I use the same code outside jfiddle it still shows different results .

Answer (score 1):

Actually a simple `padding: 0;` should remove all the white space:

http://jsfiddle.net/TAxuD/1/

Comment: thanks for prompt reply , 
in jsfiddle i can see that the padding is still 1px between the select and the option elements top-left (As shown by the Accessiblity explorer) .. Also when i use the same code outside jsfiddle . it defaults back to 3px  padding.

Comment: @Prakash "Accessiblity explorer"? What do you mean with that? Which browser you are using?

Comment: I am using IE9 . Accessiblity explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631969.aspx

Comment: @Prakash Is there a white space even in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/TAxuD/2/ ? with `* { padding: 0; }`. According to firebug the the `<option>`-tags got padding by default too.

Comment: Hi,  yes there is still 1px margin as shown by the new image in my original post. I am really not sure how the  page that got created ASP.NET has no space  :(  . But thanks a lot for  the prompt responses